# How to solve Permission denied error on Mac when setting up a Tezos node and running alphanet.sh

Tags: node

I am trying to get a Tezos node up on Mac OS.

Ran the following in sequence in a Tezos directory I created:

```
curl -o alphanet.sh https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/raw/master/scripts/alphanet.sh

chmod +x alphanet.sh

curl -o mainnet.sh https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/raw/master/scripts/alphanet.sh

chmod +x mainnet.sh

.alphanet.sh start
```

I got the following output:

```
./alphanet.sh start
alphanet: Pulling from tezos/tezos
169185f82c45: Pull complete 
031fa7e01ede: Pull complete 
d5d4e25743c2: Pull complete 
364461b15805: Pull complete 
b6a3283d274d: Pull complete 
4b84709a71b4: Pull complete 
c330adfaf0dd: Pull complete 
037a72f331fc: Pull complete 
4515c67d4d5d: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:ab1fe87b5588b76e38210a3589d3dad269aef6d154849fabeef5815aaa9aa0b4
Status: Downloaded newer image for tezos/tezos:alphanet
Creating network "alphanet_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "alphanet_node_data" with default driver
Creating volume "alphanet_client_data" with default driver
Creating alphanet_node_1 ... done
Creating alphanet_endorser-003-PsddFKi3_1 ... done
Creating alphanet_baker-003-PsddFKi3_1    ... done
Creating alphanet_accuser-003-PsddFKi3_1  ... done
Warning: the container contains a new version of 'alphanet.sh'.
You might run './alphanet.sh update_script' to synchronize.
```

So I ran:

```
.alphanet.sh update_script
```

And got:

```
-bash: ./alphanet.sh: Permission denied
...
```

Tried curl on the original URL and run start but the permission is denied now.

Comment: Are you trying to run mainnet or alphanet ?

Comment: What is the permissions of alphanet.sh now ? Did you chmod +x after the update ?

Comment: you need to do `chmod +x alphanet.sh` after the script was updated, it lost its executable permission when overwrittened. By the way, interestingly, `alphanet.sh` and `mainnet.sh` are the same file, the code reads what the name of the file to do different things.

Comment: Thanks @Frank, running chmod again after the update

Comment: @Frank hey Frank can you please post this as answer since this is the right answer ? Tx!

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to do `chmod +x alphanet.sh` again after the script was updated from `.alphanet.sh update_script`. Basically, the file lost its executable permission after being overwrittened (since it's a whole new file!). By the way, interestingly, `alphanet.sh` and `mainnet.sh` are the same file, the script reads what the name of the file to do different things such as grabbing a different docker containers.